# Concatenating columns in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, concatenation

Need some help in concatenating columns 1 and 2 as seen in screenshot.

[image]

There will be further entries in column 2, perhaps 'Blue'. I would want '1 Blue' '2 Blue' '3 Blue', etc starting off from under the '6 Indigo' entry.

Hope that makes sense! Very much new to excel, and need to get this sorted out soon.

EDIT: I do need to combine all of column A with all of column B.

Comment: Just for clarification: Do you want to combine everything in column A with everything in column B?

Comment: Yes :)
Added to post.

Comment: It should be a rather easy task in VBA. Is that an option for you?

Comment: Wouldn't even know how to use it, could give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell C2 you can input the formula below, and fill the formula down to C13 (or whatever).

```
=OFFSET($A$2,MOD(ROW()-2,COUNTA(A:A)-1),0)&" "&OFFSET($B$2,INT((ROW()-2)/(COUNTA(A:A)-1)),0)
```

**Explanation:**

The first part `OFFSET($A$2,MOD(ROW()-2,COUNTA(A:A)-1),0)` looks up the appropriate cell from column A.  `COUNTA(A:A)-1` counts number of items in column A (minus one for the header i.e. Row 1).  `MOD(ROW()-2,COUNTA(A:A)-1)` computes the remainder when the current row (C2...C13) is divided by number of items in column A.  This value would appear as (0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5) in cells (C2...C13); offsetting these values to reference `$A$2` returns the correct row in column A.

`&" "&` inserts a space in between.

The second part `OFFSET($B$2,INT((ROW()-2)/(COUNTA(A:A)-1)),0)` is similar to the first part.  However it computes the quotient instead of the remainder.  Relevant values for (C2..C13) would be (0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1).  Offsetting these to reference `$B$2` returns "Violet" or "Indigo" or any text that follows.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to complete this would be to write a VBA(Visual Basic for Applications) script which is the programming language behind Macros in Excel.

The logic behind it (sorry I don't know the code off the top of my head) would be:

```
x = 0 
ForEach entry in column a
    ForEach entry in column b
         Set value of cell c1 + x
         x + 1
```

Comment: Yikes! I've no clue about VBA. 
Thanks, though!